# A question regarding probablity in basketball - Shoot the 2 to Tie or the 3 to Win?

Tags: probability

I recently read an old post regarding this question and have my doubt about the author's conclusion. You can find the original post here if you'd like to read the whole story. 
[[Original Post]](http://www.familyadvantagenetwork.com/2014/03/22/fun-with-math-shoot-the-2-to-tie-or-the-3-to-win/)

I would briefly state the question here:

At almost the end of the basketball game, there were only a few seconds left and your team had the ball. Your team was down by two and, you, as the coach, faced the choice to ask your player to go for a two-pointer to tie and then try to win in overtime, or ask them to try to make a last-second three-pointer to win the game.

1. The probability for making 2-point is 45%.
2. The probability for making 3-point is 33%.
3. The chance of either team winning in overtime is 50%.

The conclusion the author drew was that the three-pointer has higher chance to "win" because the probability for the team make a two-pointer and then winning in overtime is 22.5%, which is smaller than 33%, shot a three-pointer to win.

I found it's interesting because at first, I believe that the math here is fine for two-pointer to tie and then went for the overtime. The chance for that scenario is 22.5%, same as the author perceived.

However, considering that taking the three-pointer would have 67% chance lost the game, but taking the two-pointer the chance was 55%. After achieving a tie scenario by making a two-pointer, the chance to win would be 50%, which looks a good advice to me. I know this way I treat the overtime winning probability independently.

So here is the question, is it ok for me to look at the case this way? Is really a good advice based on the calculated probability to take the three-pointer to win, or should we try a two-pointer to tie and seek for 50% win scenario? What is the appropriate way to use probability helping on deciding a situation like this?

Thank you for your answering.

Comment: Ask yourself this: Which is better: (i) winning (ii) having a 50% chance of winning?

Comment: I don't understand why the down-vote. Did I ask the question in a wrong place? or using a wrong format? Asking a question here seems intimidating?

Comment: We were not meant to understand downvotes. Here it could be that you asked a question that it seems you really already know the answer to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shoot the two point shot the chance of losing is $55\%$ that you miss the shot plus $\frac 12 \cdot 45\%$ that you hit the shot and lose in overtime.  This adds up to $77.5\%$.  As this is greater than the $67\%$ chance of losing if you shoot the three pointer, you should shoot the three.  This is just looking at the complementary event to winning, so it should give the same answer.  You need to add the two different ways to lose for the two point shot.

Comment: Omg. My probability knowledge is really getting rusty. Thank you very much for explaining.